# Laravel 5.3 doesn't return JSON format

Tags: json, laravel-5.3

When I try to return records from a table on the page, it spits out everything as raw data on a single line, making it ugly and unreadable.

How can I make it return properly formatted records as JSON?

**EDIT:**

It prints out this:

```
{"id":4,"title":"My Second New Card","created_at":"2016-09-05 12:06:32","updated_at":"2016-09-05 12:06:32"}
```

And I want it to print out like this:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "My Second New Card",
    "created_at": "2016-09-05 12:06:32",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-05 12:06:32"
}
```

Comment: Whats the output? Whats your code?

Comment: If using Google Chrome, you can install an extension, such as `JSONView` or `JSON Formatter` (the latter I believe is used in videos on Laracasts). Similar extensions should exist for Firefox.